# Remove vertical space above list in cell with color

Tags: color, lists, vertical-spacing, cell

When a list is the first item in a cell, it has a big vertical space above. In order to remove this space, classical answers are based on inserting `\@minipagetrue` before the list.
Unfortunately, this does not seem sufficient when colors come into play:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}}
ABCDE
&
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\trivlist
\item
ABCDE
\endtrivlist
\end{minipage}
&
\@minipagetrue
\trivlist
\item
ABCDE
\endtrivlist
&
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\trivlist
\item
\color_select:n{green}
ABCDE
\endtrivlist
\end{minipage}
&
\@minipagetrue
\trivlist
\item
\color_select:n{green}
ABCDE
\endtrivlist
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

With output
[image: 5 ABCDE]

I would like the green ABCDE on the right to be vertically aligned with the left one, without using a minipage.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `\leavevmode` before `\color_select:n` will solve your problem.

```
\@minipagetrue
\trivlist
\item \leavevmode
\color_select:n{green}
ABCDE
\endtrivlist
```

[image]

---

But here is a better solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. It provides `varwidth` library and `measure=vbox` option for lists, and `stretch=-1` option for removing vertical spaces above lists.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\SetTblrInner[tblr]{measure=vbox,stretch=-1,colsep=0mm}
\setlist[trivlist]{nosep}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={XXXXX},hlines}
ABCDE
&
\begin{trivlist}
\item ABCDE
\end{trivlist}
&
\begin{trivlist}
\item ABCDE
\end{trivlist}
&
\begin{trivlist}
\item \leavevmode\color{green}ABCDE
\end{trivlist}
&
\begin{trivlist}
\item \leavevmode\color{green}ABCDE
\end{trivlist}
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why isn't `\leavevmode` a part of the `\item` command ?

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS I think that would cause problems in other use cases. But I can not give you an example at present.

Comment: So this solution is only valid if the `\item` body is in horizontal mode. Is there a solution without `\leavevmode`?

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS Use `\textcolor` instead of `\color`.

Comment: The argument or `\textcolor` is in horizontal mode, which is equivalent to using `\leavevmode`.